# Riesz-Markov-Kakutani Theorem: Various Versions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem usually comes in various versions.
So I'm a little bit confused and wondering which of these are right.

Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact space. Then:

- Complex Measures: $\mathcal{M}(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega))\cong\mathcal{C}_c(\Omega)^*$
- Regular Measures: $\mathcal{M}_r(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega))\cong\mathcal{C}_c(\Omega)'$
- Positive Measures: $\mathcal{M}_p(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega))\cong\mathcal{C}_c(\Omega)°$

where $X^*$ denotes the linear functionals, $X'$ the continuous linear functionals and $X^*$ the positive linear functionals $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$.
The first two equivalences are meant in the sense of vector spaces whereas the last one only as something in the sense of cones I guess.

Comment: @paulgarrett: I actually thought about it ^^ good will do it!

Comment: @paulgarrett: I can see only the "And..." comment. Did you write another comment as well before that?

Comment: Oh, no, just the "And maybe, ..." and then the "Good. ...", and this one itself. Just thinking to remove comments that no longer reflect the state, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett: I think it is good and ok to leave these kind of comments so next people can follow the progress/history in the thread - but thats just personally...

Comment: Perhaps you're right... Hard to know what's useful back-story and what's clutter. Ok, having deleted my earlier comment, the point, for the record, was a suggestion to add Kakutani's name to "Riesz-Markov". Indeed, for a long time people in the west only used the label "Riesz", not being aware of Markov's contribution, either.